# UIView did appear?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I'm wondering, is there a way to get a delegate or something, when a particular `UIView` has been shown on the screen ?

Answer (score 46):

Swift version. Inside your UIView class just:

```
override func willMove(toWindow newWindow: UIWindow?) {
    super.willMove(toWindow: newWindow)

    if newWindow == nil {
        // UIView disappear
    } else {
        // UIView appear
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that when view will disappear from screen this might get called 3 times (first with nil, then with window and then again with nil) which might not be what you expected, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484518/willmovetowindow-is-called-twice

Answer (score 29):

Try these:

```
– didAddSubview:
– willRemoveSubview:
– willMoveToSuperview:
– didMoveToSuperview
– willMoveToWindow:
– didMoveToWindow
- viewDidAppear:
```

Comment: None of these appear to be called after autolayout so you can't adjust the view's children and have it keep.

Answer (score 27):

If you manage your logic directly inside the UIView, use:

```
- didMoveToSuperview
```

If you manage your logic inside a UIViewController, use :

```
- viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are managing the `UIView` via a `UIViewController`, then you can use the `-viewDidAppear:` method:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated {
   //do stuff...
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Another way to find out when a control is on screen is to subclass the View or Control and override `drawRect`...

However, it's called when it's drawn and not only when first shown. So it's only sometimes what you want. It worked for my case. Make sure to call super as well! =)