# Detect when the View has been (re)shown

Tags: ios, swift

As the title suggests, how can I detect when a user sees a UIViewController. This is slightly different from `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()`, both of which are run only when the app is first launched. What I am looking for is something like `viewDidAppear()`, but runs *every time* the view literally appears to the user (i.e. when the app is re-opened from the background or when the app is shown after the device is re-woken from sleep).

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIView did appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060958/uiview-did-appear)

Comment: viewDidAppear call every time you show your view controller, viewDidLoad called once when VC created

Comment: Create a variable in user defaults and increase it in `viewDidAppear()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidAppear` actually happens every time that view "appears", rather than just once on app load. For example, in an application that uses a `UITabBarController`, every time you press a tab, the view will switch to a specific view controller and the view controller's `viewDidAppear` method will get called.

To detect when the view appears from the background you need to register for notifications for `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: The notification is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!